# Customize Filter Icon and filter pane in a Modern Experience document library

Tags: filter, modern-document-library, sharepoint-on

I am learning that the modern experience of SharePoint Online does not leave much room for customization. I had a request from the line of business to make the filter ICON considerably more visible for some of their novice users. I know with the modern experience within a document library the default location is to the right of library designated by the filter icon. I was asked to make it more obvious and basically boldly in the users face when a user opens the library. I have been looking for a setting that would allow me to make such a customization to no avail.
Does anyone know of a way to do this if at all using the Modern Experience?

Answer (score 1):

You need to inject JS file using SPFx extension.

https://www.sharepointpals.com/post/step-by-step-procedure-to-add-a-js-file-to-all-pages-in-a-spfx-modern-pages-using-sharepoint-framework-extension/

Code required to change properties of filter icon

```
$("button[name='Filters pane'] i").style = "font-size:22px;font-weight:bold";
```

Comment: But will this work in modern experience in SharePoint online?

Comment: yes...spfx extension works on Modern experience only..